# filter todo keywords and shows contents

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I want to list all items with specified TODO and then export into html.
 `C-c a T` is used, but it only shows the headlines such as

```
TODO 1
TODO 2
...
```

How can I show that:

```
TODO 1
blablablabla
....
TODO 2
blablablabla
...
```

Also I use `C-c / T`, but when I export to html, it exports all items.

Comment: Here is a related thread that contains some comments with a partial solution:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/18390/2287

Answer (score 1):

To show the first few lines of an entry in an agenda view use the entry text view mode: `v E`.  The number of lines shown can be configured by setting `org-agenda-entry-text-maxlines`.